# Cannot get WiFi to work on otherwise fine RPi 3 B+ running Stretch

Tags: networking, wifi, raspbian-stretch, raspi-config

I just installed stretch on my RPi 3 B+ running Raspbian Stretch. During installation it asked for my WiFi network info. However, it wouldn't accept it. I have it now working with a wired internet connection, but how do I now try to configure WiFi again?

Comment: It would be most helpful to have the actual error messages that you are seeing.

Comment: what does this mean?  `it wouldn't accept it`

Comment: [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you might try this:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

Verify that your SSID (ESSID) is in the list.

There's a [detailed how-to for wifi configuration at the Rpi/documentation website](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md) if you want to setup wifi from the command line. And finally, the if you're running "headless" you can now edit the `wpa-supplicant` file in `/boot` on the uSD card... actually, I'm pretty sure you can do this running "with head" :) also, but it's required for wifi access if you're headless.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the problem is a mistyped SSID or passphrase, run `raspi-config`:

- Select **2 - Network Options** to set the Wifi SSID and passphrase.
- While you at it, select **4 - Localization Options** and confirm that your Wifi region is set correctly.